# Is it possible to convert from Microsoft's format to WKB?

Tags: geometry, sql-server, well-known-binary

Microsoft chose to create its own binary storage format for spatial data and it is not valid for use with any of SQL's OGC WKB functions.

Has anyone run across code to translate from Microsoft's proprietary binary format to OGC's Well Known Binary format?

Comment: There is a t-sql function .STAsText(), this will output OGC WKT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, STAsBinary() will return WKB.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933912.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried that but I used it incorrectly.  Thanks for prompting me to pull my head out and look at it from another direction!

Comment: @Chindokae, if you think this is the right answer, please accept it so that this thread is marked with a correct answer